# Directory.GetFiles get multiple files using filePattern

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How do I setup pattern to return multiple files, but only such that I am looking for.

I have a directory which contains files:

```
marks v1.csv,
marks_east.csv
marks.csv
marks_west.csv
marks23.csv
marks24.csv
```

I need **marks.csv, marks_east.csv, marks_west.csv** using `filePattern`.

Earlier I was using exact file name as I was interested in only one file. Now I want to reuse same process by modifying `filePattern`.

`var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, filePattern).OrderBy(d => new FileInfo(d).CreationTime);`

Comment: There is no file name pattern that will restrict the returned values to just those you want. You'll need some other way to filter them.

Answer (score 0):

Directory.GetFiles supports wildcards.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "marks_*.csv").OrderBy(d => new FileInfo(d).CreationTime);
```

This will not catch marks.csv though.  Regex would be very well suited for this, but alas the GetFiles function does not support regular expressions.  A quick (a bit hacky) solution might be:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "marks_*.csv");
if (File.Exists(sourceDirectory+"marks.csv"))
    files.Insert(0, "marks.csv");
files.OrderBy(d => new FileInfo(d).CreationTime);
```

Comment: That will return marks23.csv, marks24.csv etc as well. Which I don't want.

Comment: The one with marks_* won't return marks.csv whihc I do want.

Comment: Edited again.  My apologies